# Load Shortcode Content with AJAX loading implemented...?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1 and a Theme that utilizes AJAX loading.

(the site is here: http://phoenixwave.com/test/ )

I've installed a plugin to add more shortcode abilities. Problem is, once a page loads via the AJAX loading - it doesn't seem to load the shortcodes (especially anything that is animated) unless you do a hard refresh on the page.

If you go to: http://phoenixwave.com/test/portfolio and choose the only option on that page you'll see what is happening ... or not happening in this case.

I have the ability to add custom Javascript and CSS within the theme that I'm using and wondered if there would be a way to fix this problem. I've noticed other similar problems posted to Stack but they are SO code heavy that I was unsure what to learn from.

Comment: You'd probably do better asking on [wordpress.se]

Comment: Added to the site you gave ... thanks for the input. @MikeW